# SQL UniqueIdentifier

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, uniqueidentifier

I have a table called `UserCredentials` and it has a `uniqueidentifier` column `[UserCredentialId]`. When I try to create a new user, I get `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` in my first try, then when I try adding another user, it says PK cannot be duplicated. At first I had a hard time guessing what does it mean but, I think its because of my `uniqueidentifier` is not generating random id.

What to do?

**EDIT**

Here is my SQL table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserCredential](
    [UserCredentialId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [UserRoleId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Username] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [Password] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [PasswordSalt] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [PayorCode] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [ProviderCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CorporationCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Department] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [DateCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DateActivated] [datetime] NULL,
    [Deactivated] [datetime] NULL,
    [DateUpdated] [datetime] NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedBy] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [EmailAddress] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ContactNumber] [int] NULL,
    [Picture] [varbinary](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UserCredential_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserCredentialId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I already set it to (`newid()`) but still not working.

Comment: Can you post your SQL table script I mean create one.

Comment: What did you set to `newid()`?

Comment: just plain newid(). nothing more.

Comment: I think he set the DefaultValueForBinding in the field properties list of the field to NEWID().

Answer (score 2):

Set the Id of your user instance to **Guid.NewGuid();**

```
user.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Comment: Same answer I would have suggested. Guid.NewGuid();

Answer (score 1):

Change your table definition to

```
[UserCredentialId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (NEWSEQUENTIALID()) NOT NULL
```

Check why prefer NEWSEQUENTIALID than newid at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx.

> When a GUID column is used as a row identifier, using NEWSEQUENTIALID can be faster than using the NEWID function. This is because the NEWID function causes random activity and uses fewer cached data pages. Using NEWSEQUENTIALID also helps to completely fill the data and index pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can have all values in the table default to a new value during insert, much like an IDENTITY.

Run this to set the default of all inserts to use newid().

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserCredential] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_UserCredential_UserCredentialID]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [UserCredentialId]
GO
```